# refs in reactjs Component empty

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have a react-chartjs-2 element in my render function that I assign a ref to from React.createRef() but

1. refs is empty
2. the current property on my ref is null

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   const LineChart = require('react-chartjs-2').Line;

   class App extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.chartRef = React.createRef();
       this.chartObject = null;
     }

     componentDidMount() {
       this.chartObject = this.chartRef.current.getContext('2d');
       this.chartObject.update();
     }

     render() {

       return ( 
         <div className = "App">
           <LineChart 
             data = {}
             width = {600}
             height = {250}
             ref = {this.chartRef}/>
           </div>
         );
       }
     }
   ```

Comment: Are you using React 16.3?

Comment: yes, I am using 16.3 (16.3.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs):

> When the ref attribute is used on a
>   custom class component, the ref object receives the mounted instance
>   of the component as its current.

So you will not receive a `canvas` but an instance of component **when** it will mount. That's why I think when App `componentDidMount` is called the `LineChart` was not yet mounted that's why `current` is still null.

Again

`this.chartObject = this.chartRef.current.getContext('2d');`

will not work because you will receive an instance of a component, not a `canvas`.

Comment: Well this is all well and good but how to get a ref of a chart when the component (and the chart) loads (once, not using componentDidUpdate)??